# select query with wildcard not working in QT

Tags: qt, wildcard, qml, select-query

qt gives me an error when I try to put a wildcard in my select query. I need to compare a variable with a query result but putting in wildcards doesnt seem to work.please help!

```
Text{
    id: searchresults
    text: ""
    font.pixelSize: 45
    color: "black"
    opacity: 1
    x: 10

    function findHerb(value) {
        var db = getDB();                

        db.transaction(
            function(tx) {

                var rec = tx.executeSql('SELECT name FROM Herbs WHERE name LIKE "?%"', [value]);

                var r = "";

                for(var i=0; i<rec.rows.length; i++) {
                    r+= rec.rows.item(i).name + "\n"
                }

                text = r;

            }
        )

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not also include the error?

Comment: this is the error                                                      Error:  Parameter count mismatch

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hacky suggestion as it obviously doesn't address why your exact approach isn't working correctly. But my guess is that the `%` is somehow causing an issue when it expands the parameters into the statement.

Try something like this...

```
var likeVal = value + "%";
var rec = tx.executeSql('SELECT name FROM Herbs WHERE name LIKE "?"', [likeVal]);
```

Also, my other guess is that the args are parameterized for you **with** quotes already and you are making it double quote. Here is another possibility:

```
var rec = tx.executeSql('SELECT name FROM Herbs WHERE name LIKE ?%', [likeVal]);
```

Comment: The first or second suggestion? Just want to maybe update my answer so future people are clear

Comment: @GastonManrique: Dont forget to hit the checkmark if this answer solved your problem!